# How to securely measure user's time

Tags: javascript

I want to measure the time it takes for a user to complete a task (answer a quiz). I want to measure it accurately, without the network lag. Meaning, if I measure on the server side the time between 2 requests, it won't be the real time it took the user, because the network time is factored in.

But on the other hand, if I measure in javascript and post the timestamps to the server, the user will be able to see the code, and cheat by sending false timestamps, no?

How can I get the timestamps in javascript and make sure the user doesn't fake it?

Comment: You can´t! Whatever you try, the javaScript is client side and its code is visible to the experienced user - he can always find a way to send cheated timestamps. Your server needs to do the time measuring. And regarding latency - do you think your quiz game will suffer from 50ms network lag or something in that range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in client side code, any question that starts off with "How to securely..." is answered with "Not possible". Nothing, not even putting variables in a closure (because I, the evil cheating user could just change the code on my end and send it back to you).

This is the kind of validation that should be performed server side, even with the disadvantage of network latency.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here would be to measure the time using JavaScript, but also keep track of it using server-side code. That way, you can rely on the timestamps received by the client as long as you enforce a maximum difference between calculated times. I'd say a few seconds should be good enough. However, by doing so, you are creating an additional vector for failure.

Edit: A user could potentially tweak his or her time in their favor by up to the maximum enforced difference if they are able to take advantage of the (lack of) network lag.

Comment: What advantage does knowing delta time between the server value and an untrusted value from client code confer?

Comment: @jdphenix Well, realistically, it's a quiz. All the OP wants to do is get an accurate measurement of time taken to complete the quiz, which can only be obtained from an untrusted client. However, if you were to actually think about it, this method will effectively protect against malicious use. This isn't an algorithm meant to protect top secret NSA documents. Just a measurement of time. Sometimes it's smarter just to think of a solution that fits the scenario. That's what this is.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem while designing an online examination portal for my project.
I went for a hybrid approach.

1. Get time from server as user loads the page, and starts timer based on javascript. Record the start time in your database.
2. Let the timer run on client side for some time, say 30 seconds.
3. Refresh timer by making a AJAX call to server for timer reset as per the time that has passed already.
4. NOTE: try to use external javascript and obfuscate the code of timer to make guessing difficult.

This way you may not prevent user completely from modifying timer, but you can limit max possible error to 30s.